# Copying Categories in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.9

Ive got two seperate installations of Magento.

The old installation is Magento 1.4 and the new installation is 1.9.

There are about 1200 categories on the old one. I want to re-create them perfectly (including IDs) on the new one.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to move products as well?

Comment: no, just categories. perfectly. with IDs intact.

Comment: Are you looking to use "models" safer. But so slow with that amount of categories or sql queries much much faster

Comment: any possible way of copying the categories, slow or fast, would be appreciated... i will worry about the most efficient / quickest way once ive got a method that works... right now i have no methods that work... if you know of one or more methods of copying the categories over please leave it as an answer

Comment: No, you can't copy categories with ids intact. The main category table is catalog_category_entity. The columns there should be self-explanatory. Write a script to get the categories from the old database to the new database.

Comment: @DavidTay I suspected as much, add that as an answer and I will mark it correct